# Does spring jdbcTemplate scrub URL's?

Tags: java, json, oracle, rest, spring-boot

I've ran into a slight hitch in the process of building an Spring Boot API, I was hoping someone more familiar with how spring boot works behind the scenes might be able to give me some advice.

I have a @ResponseBody marked method within a controller that makes a DB query and marshal's the result to JSON like so:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/oneLibInfo",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    List<LibInfo> getOneLibInfo(@RequestParam(required = true,value = "NUC")String NUC){

    List<LibInfo> libInfos = jdbcTemplate.query(
            "select o.organisation_id, o.name, a.alias, i.service_id, i.library_system_id, i.web_catalog_baseurl, ls.LIBRARY_SYSTEM_NAME,ls.LIBRARY_SYSTEM_VENDOR,ls.QUERY_PARAM_ISBN,ls.QUERY_PARAM_TITLE,ls.QUERY_PARAM_ISBN,ls.QUERY_PARAM_AUTHOR_TITLE\n" +
                    "from ALG1.LIBRARY_SYSTEM ls\n" +
                    "  INNER JOIN ALG1.ALG_INFORMATION i on i.LIBRARY_SYSTEM_ID = ls.LIBRARY_SYSTEM_ID\n" +
                    "  inner join dir.service s on s.service_id = i.service_id\n" +
                    "  inner join dir.organisation o on o.organisation_id = s.organisation_id\n" +
                    "  inner join dir.organisation_alias a on a.organisation_id = o.organisation_id\n" +
                    "where a.alias in (?)\n" +
                    "      and a.alias_type = 'Union catalogue symbol'",
            new Object[]{NUC}
            ,new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(LibInfo.class,false)
    );
    return libInfos;
    }
```

The query when run externally to the application works fine.

It works fine within the application too, except one column fails to return: webCatalogueBaseURL.

This column, as the name implies contains a URL, returns undefined. 
I can't for the life of me figure out why. Has anyone had a problem like this before?

P.S:  Domain class used for row mapping:

```
package au.gov.nla.deeplinkhelper.domain;
```

public class LibInfo {

```
public LibInfo() {
}


public LibInfo(String name, String alias, String serviceId, String librarySystemId, String webCatalogueBaseurl, String librarySystemName, String librarySystemVendor, String queryParamIsbn, String queryParamTitle, String queryParamIssn, String queryParamAuthorTitle) {
    this.name = name;
    this.alias = alias;
    this.serviceId = serviceId;
    this.librarySystemId = librarySystemId;
    this.webCatalogueBaseurl = webCatalogueBaseurl;
    this.librarySystemName = librarySystemName;
    this.librarySystemVendor = librarySystemVendor;
    this.queryParamIsbn = queryParamIsbn;
    this.queryParamTitle = queryParamTitle;
    this.queryParamIssn = queryParamIssn;
    this.queryParamAuthorTitle = queryParamAuthorTitle;
}

String name;
String alias;
String serviceId;
String librarySystemId;
String webCatalogueBaseurl;
String librarySystemName;
String librarySystemVendor;
String queryParamIsbn;
String queryParamTitle;
String queryParamIssn;
String queryParamAuthorTitle;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAlias() {
    return alias;
}

public void setAlias(String alias) {
    this.alias = alias;
}

public String getServiceId() {
    return serviceId;
}

public void setServiceId(String serviceId) {
    this.serviceId = serviceId;
}

public String getLibrarySystemId() {
    return librarySystemId;
}

public void setLibrarySystemId(String librarySystemId) {
    this.librarySystemId = librarySystemId;
}

public String getWebCatalogueBaseurl() {
    return webCatalogueBaseurl;
}

public void setWebCatalogueBaseurl(String webCatalogueBaseurl) {
    this.webCatalogueBaseurl = webCatalogueBaseurl;
}

public String getLibrarySystemName() {
    return librarySystemName;
}

public void setLibrarySystemName(String librarySystemName) {
    this.librarySystemName = librarySystemName;
}

public String getLibrarySystemVendor() {
    return librarySystemVendor;
}

public void setLibrarySystemVendor(String librarySystemVendor) {
    this.librarySystemVendor = librarySystemVendor;
}

public String getQueryParamIsbn() {
    return queryParamIsbn;
}

public void setQueryParamIsbn(String queryParamIsbn) {
    this.queryParamIsbn = queryParamIsbn;
}

public String getQueryParamTitle() {
    return queryParamTitle;
}

public void setQueryParamTitle(String queryParamTitle) {
    this.queryParamTitle = queryParamTitle;
}

public String getQueryParamIssn() {
    return queryParamIssn;
}

public void setQueryParamIssn(String queryParamIssn) {
    this.queryParamIssn = queryParamIssn;
}

public String getQueryParamAuthorTitle() {
    return queryParamAuthorTitle;
}

public void setQueryParamAuthorTitle(String queryParamAuthorTitle) {
    this.queryParamAuthorTitle = queryParamAuthorTitle;
}
```

}

And this is an example output returned from the rest controller:

```
data
:
Array(1)
0
:
alias
:
"NSCU:L"
librarySystemId
:
"1194"
librarySystemName
:
"Alma-test3 NSCU"
librarySystemVendor
:
"Ex libris"
name
:
"University Library Lismore"
queryParamAuthorTitle
:
null
queryParamIsbn
:
"$$ISBN$$&tab=Everything&search_scope=MyInst_and_CI&vid=61SCU_INST:61SCU&offset=0"
queryParamIssn
:
null
queryParamTitle
:
"$$TITLE$$&tab=Everything&search_scope=MyInst_and_CI&vid=61SCU_INST:61SCU&offset=0"
serviceId
:
"4216"
webCatalogueBaseurl
:
null
```

That last entry is the problem one.

This is using *SpringBoot 2.01* with an *Oracle DB*.

Only the column containing the URL seems to fizz out.

Comment: That certainly would be an unexpected and undocumented feature of `JdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database column is named `web_catalog_baseurl` but your bean property is named `webCatalogueBaseurl`. `catalog` vs `catalogue` so to the  bean mapper it is not the same.

Rename the bean property to `webCatalogBaseurl`

```
private String webCatalogBaseurl;

public String getWebCatalogBaseurl() {
    return webCatalogBaseurl;
}

public void setWebCatalogBaseurl(String webCatalogBaseurl) {
    this.webCatalogBaseurl = webCatalogBaseurl;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I went through the names but missed that.